# Используя Regex удалить всё, кроме того, что подходит под паттерн

Tags: java

Собственно вопрос в том, как реализовать код который из `string` будет выбирать только ту часть, что удовлетворяет условиям, а всё остальное удалять. В моём случае имеется переменная

```
String host= "my_host_192.168.0.1"
```

Нужно чтобы остался только этот участок кода `192.168.0.1`

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `regEx` не удаляет ничего. С его помощью можно проверить вхождение подстроки.

Comment: Если первая часть строки всегда будет `"my_host_"`, тогда `String result = host.substring(8);`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
    public class RegExpTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String host = "my_host_192.168.0.1";
            System.out.println(host.replaceAll(
                "\\w+_((([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))",
                "$1")
            );
        }
    }
```

[Ссылка на RegExp для IP](https://www.regextester.com/22)